# Mutual Independent Events Criteria

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability

According to my understanding, the following statement is false.

For any $n$ events ${A_i}^n_{i=1}$, if $P(⋂^n_{i=1}A_i) = ∑^n_{i=1}P(A_i)$, then ${A_i}^n_{i=1}$ are mutually independent.

But, I was told that it is True. I am confused now, I thought instead of summation (∑) of probabilities, it had to be the product. What am I missing?

Comment: Indeed there being a sum makes no sense. It should be the product.

Comment: Though I'd say the statement is not true even with the product, because of $A_1=A_2$, $A_3=\emptyset$.

Comment: It is true, tough, that $A_1,\cdots, A_n$ are independent if and only if $P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n B_i\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n P(B_i)$ for all $B_1,\cdots, B_n$ such that for all $i$ either $B_i=A_i$ or $B_i=A_i^c$, if and only if $P(\bigcap_{i=1}^m A_{j_i})=\prod_{i=1}^m P(A_{j_i})$ for all subcollections $A_{j_1}, \cdots, A_{j_m}$, $m<n$.